# Find Linkbutton value on change function of DropdownList inside Gridview using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a databind `LinkButton` inside DataList in `Gridview` along with databind `DropdownList` in separate columns. I want to get the value of LinkButton on `change` function of DropDownList.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Screening Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlScreeningStatus" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"
                    CssClass="selectpicker">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Response">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInterviewsHeader" runat="server"><b>INTERVIEWS</b></asp:Label>
                <ul><asp:DataList ID="dlInterviewList" ShowHeader="true" runat="server" Visible="true" Caption="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbnInterview" runat="server" Visible="true" OnClick="lbnInterviewSchedule_OnClick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("ScreeningStatusName") %>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList></ul>
                <asp:Label ID="lbQuestionsHeader" runat="server"><b>RESPONSES</b></asp:Label>
                <ul><asp:DataList ID="dlQuestionnaireList" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lbnQuestionnaireResponse"  runat="server" Visible="true" OnClick="lbnQuestionnaireResponse_OnClick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Name") + " - " + Eval("TotalScore") + " pts" %>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList></ul>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $("[id$='ddlScreeningStatus']").change(function () {

        $this = $(this);
        ddlScreeningStatus = $this.val();
        var interviewResponse = $this.parent().next();
        var interviewResponseValue = interviewResponse.find("[id$='lbnInterview']").val();
        var questionnaireResponse = $this.parent().next();
        var questionnaireResponseValue = questionnaireResponse.find("[id$='lbnQuestionnaireResponse']").val();
    });
});
```

Comment: What problem you have? Also add the generated html to have better idea of html structure and required selectors.

Comment: In JQuery the variable is not returning the value. I am not that good at JQuery so don't know how to find control and get value.

Comment: Please get the source of the page from browser and add in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at generated html you can view the id of dropdownlist.

```
$("[id$='ddlScreeningStatus']")
```

is not correct because the id will be different per row.

You have to change it according to the new name.
Also

```
find("[id$='lbnInterview']")
```

is not correct.
When you find the dropdownlist you can:

1. navigate the dom to get other controls as lbnInterview
2. split dropdownlist id and get the index to get other controls id.